# django-profiles: how to edit a profile from a user different from current user

Tags: django

newbie django question

I'm using django-profiles to display a list of profiles, using profiles.views.profile_list view, and individual profiles, using profiles.views.profile_detail.

For each individual profile, I wanted to add a link to edit the profile, only if the profile corresponds to the current user. My first attempt was:

```
(...)
{% block content %}
<p>Profile detail info for {{ user }} </p>
<ul>
    <li>{{ user.username }}

        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <a href="{% url profiles_edit_profile user.username %}">edit</a>
        {% endif %}

    </li>
    <li>{{ user.get_profile.url }}</li> (...)
```

But then I hit the obvious issue: edit_profile is meant to edit the current user profile, so doesn't take username/ id as arguments, and django cannot reverse the url, because in fact I don't have a url to edit a named user's profile.

What's the best strategy here? copy the profiles app into my project and add the named user edit profile view? Or is there a way to do it without having to have a local project copy of the app - which I guess would be preferable?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `edit_profile` view already enforces that the profile being edited is the current user's profile. You don't need to pass any arguments to it:

```
(...)
{% block content %}
<p>Profile detail info for {{ user }} </p>
<ul>
    <li>{{ user.username }}

        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <a href="{% url profiles_edit_profile %}">edit</a>
        {% endif %}

    </li>
    <li>{{ user.get_profile.url }}</li> (...)
```

Comment: yes that's right, thanks, I didn't think it through properly :)